# Solving linear equation mod m

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

I am watching cryptography classes because I want to understand the math behind bitcoin's algorithm. This is a hobby, but I am having a **brainfart** watching [this part of the lecture](https://youtu.be/AELVJL0axRs?t=5269):

The equations are:

$$
S_2 = AS_1 + B \mod m
$$

$$
S_3 = AS_2 + B \mod m
$$

He solved them and got:

$$
A = (S_2 - S_3)(S_1 - S_2)^{-1} \mod m
$$

$$
B = S_2 - S_1(S_2 - S_3)(S_1 - S_2)^{-1} \mod m
$$

I was able to solve for A and arrive at the same result but not B, How did he arrive at the resulting equation for B? I can see that A was plugged into the first equation but I wasn't able to get to the same result.

Comment: Subtract the 2nd equation from the first.

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  Homework problems are allowed, as long as the protocol is
observed.

Comment: You have $s_1$ and $S_1$, also $s_2$ and $S_2$, $s_3$ and $S_3$. If these are meant to be the same, please edit so they actually are the same. It wouldn't hurt to look at the help pages on formatting mathematics so you get $s_2$ instead of s2, and so on.

Comment: @user2661923 this is not homework, I am learning this stuff as a hobby because I want to understand the math behind bitcoin's algorithms. I was able to solve for A but no B.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I corrected it, it was a typo.

Comment: Note that  $S_1 - S_2$ is invertible $\bmod m$ iff it is coprime to the modulus, so the solutions are not valid if this is not the case.

Comment: You can use Cramer Rule when the determinant is invertible $\bmod m,\,$ e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3388712/242), or do the same by  (Gaussian) *elimination*.

Comment: "this is not homework" : as I indicated, that is irrelevant.  Please follow the instructions in the article, with all of your responses inserted directly into your posting, rather than in the comments.

Comment: From the first equation, you get $B=S_2-AS_1$ (OK, congruent, not equal – I'm being lazy). Now replace $A$ by the expression you got for it earlier.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I see, it was my interpretation of the symbol that was incorrect, I should have used congruent, if you create an answer to this topic, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtracting the second congruence from the first, we get
$$
S_3-S_2\equiv AS_2-AS_1\equiv A(S_2-S_1)\pmod m,
$$
whence $A\equiv(S_3-S_2)(S_2-S_1)^{-1}\pmod m$ (provided $S_2-S_1$ is invertible, modulo $m$).

Then the first equation can be rewritten as $B\equiv S_2-AS_1\mod m$, and substituting for $A$ the expression we just found earlier,
$$
B\equiv S_2-S_1(S_3-S_2)(S_2-S_1)^{-1}\pmod m
$$